# PHP: escapeshellarg() to which I can pass the desired escaping convention

Tags: php

I'm looking for a PHP function similar to [escapeshellarg()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) that would allow me to pass the OS for which the escaping should be done as a parameter.

My use case is this: I am on Windows where `escapeshellarg()` surrounds the arg with double quotes. However, the command being constructed will eventually be run on a Linux system via SSH where single quotes must be used. So I'm looking for something like:

```
$escapedArg = escapeshellarg($arg, LINUX_OS);
```

Answer (score 1):

I found what I needed in [Drush](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush), specifically in these functions:

- `_drush_escapeshellarg_linux()`
- `_drush_escapeshellarg_windows()`